# Convert string into integer

Tags: python, string

How can I convert string into integer and  remove every character from that change.
Example:

`S = "--r10-"` I want to have this: `S = 10`

This not work:

```
S = "--10-"
int(S)
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you know how you strings look like but you can always use regular expressions to get the relevant information out. \d gives you numbers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `filter(str.isdigit, s)` to keep only those characters of `s` that are digits:

```
>>> s = "--10-"
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
10
```

Note that this might lead to unexpected results for strings that contain multiple numbers

```
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, "12 abc 34"))
1234
```

or negative numbers

```
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, "-10"))
10
```

**Edit**: To make this work for `unicode` objects instead of `str` objects, use

```
int(filter(unicode.isdigit, u"--10-"))
```

Comment: I have this message in my code: 'descriptor 'isdigit' requres a 'str' object but recived a 'unicode' :( any suggestion?

Comment: You could also use [`operator.methodcaller("isdigit")`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) so it will work with both str and unicode.

Answer (score 4):

remove all non digits first like that:

```
int(''.join(c for c in "abc123def456" if c.isdigit()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just strip off `-` and `r`:

```
int("--r10-".strip('-r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex replace with /w to replace non word characters with "" empty string. then cast it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Sven Marnach's answer using `filter` and `isdigit`, but if you want you can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'\d+')  #  '\d' means digit, '+' means one or more
>>> int(pat.search('--r10-').group(0))
10
```

If there are multiple integers in the string, it pulls the first one:

```
>>> int(pat.search('12 abc 34').group(0))
12
```

If you need to deal with negative numbers use this regex:

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r'\-{0,1}\d+')  # '\-{0,1}' means zero or one dashes
>>> int(pat.search('negative: -8').group(0))
-8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and does not require you to import any packages.

```
def _atoi(self, string):
    i = 0
    for c in string:
        i += ord(c)
    return i
```